# make hc-sr04 receive from another one

Tags: microcontroller, ultrasonic-sensors

I have 3 ultrasonic Sensor (HC-SR04), i want to use one of them as transmitter, and the other as receiver, i want to let the first one send ultra Sonic waves and the other receive these waves from the same transmitter.

how can i do that ?

i tried to send trigger for each ultrasonic and connect them on different pins on PIC, but its now work.

its something like this [project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWgInUW6A8w) but using HC-SR04

Answer (score 1):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.micropik.com/PDF/HCSR04.pdf) the sensors automatically sends and receives the pulses, you would need to independently control the speakers and microphones I am not aware of any ultrasonic sensors that give you that fine control, you would need to purchase separate ultrasonic transmitters and receivers, and construct the appropriate filtering and amplification circuitry for both.

Answer (score 0):

The sensor have trig and echo pins. Simular to your video, you can do that as pen is transmiter and others are receiver. Send from trigger pen (dont listen from echo)and count signals from transciver inputs(dont send any signal from trig).